# Sublime text 3 selected tab on top

Tags: sublimetext3

In Sublime Text 3. 
Is there any way to place the selected tab on the top over the other opened tabs?

Searched all over stackoverflow without success.

Screenshot 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/wN516.jpg

Comment: What do you mean by *on the top over the other opened tabs*? Please provide a image or a example of the thing you want to avoid.

Comment: i have added a link to an screenshot, as you can see the selected tab is under other tabs, i would like to have it always on top.

Comment: Not exactly what you want, but maybe the answer to [this question](http://superuser.com/questions/698212/how-to-disable-overlapping-tabs-or-scrolling-tabs-in-sublime-text-3) is useful for this.

Comment: Not perfect but helps, thank you sergioFC